# One if works the next does not?

Tags: java, android-studio

The first if statement works but once the value is set too true the second if statement should trigger but it does not see code below:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    TextView Serial = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.LastSerialScanned));
    TextView Location = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.LastLocationScanned));
    if(hasSerial == false)// does trigger
    {
        if(Scan.getText().length() == 8)
        {
            Serial.setText(Scan.getText());
            hasSerial = true;
            Location.setText("");
            Scan.setText("");
        }
    }
    if(hasSerial == true)// does not trigger
    {
        Location.setText(Scan.getText());
        hasSerial = false;
    }
}
```

Any idea why? I am sure it is obvious but this is my first time working with android studio so I am just missing something. It also did not trigger when I had a simple else statement there

Comment: `Scan.getText().length()` isn't 0?

Comment: So I can trigger the top option 100 times and it never triggers the hasSerial == true line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first block

```
if(hasSerial == false)// does trigger
{
    if(Scan.getText().length() == 8)
    {
        Serial.setText(Scan.getText());
        hasSerial = true;
        Location.setText("");
        Scan.setText("");
    }
}
```

triggers it changes `hasSerial` to true and changes `Location` and `Scan` to empty strings.

Because `hasSerial` is now true, this following block:

```
if(hasSerial == true)// does not trigger
{
    Location.setText(Scan.getText());
    hasSerial = false;
}
```

is also executed (in the same call to `onTextChanged()`) and sets `hasSerial` back to false.

The other line in this block has no effect, since both `Scan` and `Location` have been set to empty strings just before.

What you probably intended to do was something like:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    TextView Serial = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.LastSerialScanned));
    TextView Location = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.LastLocationScanned));
    if (!hasSerial) {  // does trigger
        if (Scan.getText().length() == 8)             {
            Serial.setText(Scan.getText());
            hasSerial = true;
            Location.setText("");
            Scan.setText("");
        }
    } else {
        Location.setText(Scan.getText());
        hasSerial = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it by adding && Scan.getText().Length()==3 to the if statement. Once I figured out how to add breaks and step through it the answer was more than obvious. Thanks all.